# Markdown and HTML code error

Tags: html, markdown

When I try to compile in Marldown the following html code

```
<table id="toc" class="toc">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="toctitle">
<h2>Contents</h2>
</div>
<ul>
<li>[toto](#toto)</li>
<li>[tata](#tata)</li>
<li>[titi](#titi)</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

with command :

```
 perl Markdown.pl --html4tags toto.md > toto.html
```

I get something like this in the HTML page:

```
Contents
[toto](#toto)
[tata](#tata)
```

while MOU software or online like Dillinger provide the right results (only toto and tata without the brackets...)
I have the same problem when I write a table with Markdown code.

Does someone have an idea of where it may come?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't replicate the issue you have, but perhaps you are using a different Markdown parser. Could you type `less $(which Markdown.pl)` and see if the fourth line is `use Text::Markdown qw(markdown);`. If not, it would be good to indicate what parser you are using and where you got it from.

Comment: it returns "Missing filename ("less --help" for help)" 
I should miss something. Sorry I'm a beginner ...

Comment: Try installing Text::Markdown (`cpan Text::Markdown`) and use the Markdown.pl from there (you should be able to call it without `perl`, i.e. `Markdown.pl toto.md`.

Comment: I had some issues with my cpan, but it's ok now. 
I confirm that the fourth line is use Text::Markdown qw(markdown);
And I still have the same results even with Markdown.pl toto.md

Answer (score 0):

the `</li>` on the 11th line should not be there, remove it.

Comment: it's a copy-paste error sorry. It does not change the problem.

Comment: Just wondering - why are you using a table for html markup?! Did you put a blank line before and after the table, which Markdown wants?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I write it in Markdown of course. And I get something like this :

| Tables | Are | Cool | |----------|:-------------:|------:| | col 1 is | left-aligned | $1600 | | col 2 is | centered | $12 | | col 3 is | right-aligned | $1 |